# recursive iterator PHP remove the 1st 5 lines output

Tags: php

i have these codes and the out put below. i need to look like that at the below final output.

```
<?php

    $path = realpath('/cert/cert/cert/p12');

    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        echo $name ."\n<br>";
    }

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\.
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\..
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\.
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\..
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\12312@dsadf.com.p12
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\asdasda@dasda.com.p12
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\dfgdf@fsdfs.com.p12
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\534534@24423423.com.p12
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\rewry.rewrwe.com.p12
```

i want to remove the 1st five output lines

```
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\.
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\..
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\.
C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\..
```

to make the output like this Final output

```
 C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\12312@dsadf.com.p12
 C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\asdasda@dasda.com.p12
 C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\dfgdf@fsdfs.com.p12
 C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\534534@24423423.com.p12
 C:\Cert\Cert\cert\p12\24by7\rewry.rewrwe.com.p12
```

Comment: You want to remove the first 5 based on what?

Comment: Why not simply set the path as `$path = realpath('/cert/cert/cert/p12/24by7');` and then just ignore anything that matches `is_dir()`?; or use a `regexIterator` to filter on files with a `p12` extension?

Comment: the path /cert/cert/cert/p12/ consist of folders thats why

Comment: If you don't have a particular logic, apply array_slice on objects array OR try unsetting the 1st five positions of objects array and reset indexes

Comment: Then explain the logic of what you need to remove